# Client is catching generic message from Node server not message I am trying to send

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am not sure what is going on here, but when I am sending back a 400, or some other error request back to the client, node is setting a generic message instead of the one I am sending back. Here is a snippet from my server and what gets put in the UI on the client

Server:

```
var noContentFound = {
    error:true,
    message:'No data found for this search'
}
res.status(400).send(noContentFound);
return;
```

Client:

```
.catch(function (error) {

    let errorFromServer = {
        generalServerError:{
            error:true,
            message:error.message
        },
        ...
    };

    return errorFromServer;
    //both error, and error.message give the message "Request failed with status code 400"
});
```

So I am sending back in my server `noContentFound` object with the error message in it through `res.status(400).send(noContentFound);` But in the client the only thing that is returned in the catch function is `Request failed with status code 400` I dont have access to the message I am trying to send back.

Odd thing is, in the network tab on that call on the response tab I can see the object coming through. But `error` in the `catch` function does not give me access to that object.

Anyone know why?

EDIT:

Client Call looks like this:
Base Module:

```
getContent(obj, envBool, baseUrl, httpRequest)
    .then(function(data){
        //assign to my store object in react and emit the change
    });
```

Where the call is made module:

```
const getContent(obj, envBool, baseUrl, httpRequest){

  //set some variables and data to send

  return httpRequest.post(enviUrl,objToSend)
    .then(function(response){
        returnObj = {
            //assign returned data...
        }
        //...
        return returnObj;
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        returnObj = {
            //assign and handle error...
        }
        //...
        return returnObj;
    });

}
```

Comment: Check the full error object. Sometimes it's in error.response or error.data. How are you are making the http request in the clients side?

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat I added how my client initiates the call

Comment: Don't you have a general handler for your `400` or `404` status in your `app.js`? I've seen that in some node.js applications. Maybe the error sent to the client is being overwritten there.

Comment: Ah, I guess that is possible. I will have to look into that.

Comment: What is httpRequest? Where is that defined?

Comment: I am using Axios, and it turns out that if an error comes back from the server, 400, 500 etc, it captures that and sends back a generic message and not the response sent back from the server. I modified the file to send back the response I gave from the server.